# How to show limited children in ER Diagram

Tags: sql, check-constraints, entity-relationship

I need to make a comprehensive Entity Relationship Diagram, where, as a business rule, the child table (FK) can only have X number of rows associated to the parent (PK).

Eventually, I may use some CHECK constraint to enforce this in SQL, but how would I show this rule on the ERD? Or am I thinking too much and such business rules are not shown.

Comment: You could have ChildrenAllowed table with records of only 1-5.  Then make it part of a unique index for the child record so for a given parent there can only be as many children as record in childrenallowed.  This way the limit is controlled with data not code.  But I don't know how one would represent this on the ERD.  Except as answered by Kamil.  I try not to impose such limits using data not code to offer greater flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cardinality** is the word you're looking for. It specifies how many instances of an entity relate to one instance of another entity. It specifies the occurences a of relationship.

You have a one to many or many to many relationship between entities which means, that instead of many you can put exact number. This is obviously only marked on the ERD as a logical design model, so when translating it to a physical model you would probably use a trigger to enforce such behaviour. There are many different ways to do it, though.

**Example of one to many relationship:**

A company can hire maximum of 5 employees. Company-Employee relation is **mandatory**, meaning that there must be at least one employee working in a company (this is called **ordinality**). An employee can work in one company.

```
        1       1..5
Company ------------ Employee
```